# NoClassDefFoundError: org/cloudera/htrace/Sampler in Apache Phoenix JDBC

Tags: java, hbase, cloudera, apache-phoenix, htrace

I am new to HBase and Phoenix, and I have faced an issue with the Phoenix JDBC program in Java.

I have some sample data in a Phoenix table, and I have written a Java code to  draw the data out into the console with a select statement. 
My connection string is:`jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181` and the JDBC class I am using is :`org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver`.

While running the program I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cloudera/htrace/Sampler
```

What jar file am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have the htrace library in your build path ? So it can't find it

Comment: I have an `htrace-core-3.0.4` jar in my JAVA build path which I have added hoping to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you use maven for library ?

Comment: And verify that it doesn't any other library for work

Comment: No I am not using maven here.

Comment: Try to remove and re add the jar, it can be that rarely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the jar the program was asking for from the maven repository 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.cloudera.htrace/htrace/1.46
Exact name of the JAR would be htrace-1.46.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jar file is missing in lib .
add the jar or add in maven dependency (if you are using maven).
if its already there then check classpath of application.

Comment: The problem is I cannot  find the jar file the program is asking for. I have added Hadoop,Hbase and Phoenix libraries and I am sure most of them are not required.

Can you point me out which Jar file exactly I am missing?

Comment: htrace-core-2.00.jar
use the appropriate version.

htrace-1.45.jar this jar also contains same. check the version before using